# How to combine aggregate per month and splitting a data set at a certain date

Tags: r, date, split, aggregate, subset

I am trying to create a monthly average of precipitation values of two different time sets, but I can't get the data to be split into two before making the aggregation.

I have a dataset of daily precipitation data from 01-01-2006 to 31-12-2099 and I want to aggregate per month over the time period of (01-01-2015 to 31-12-2054) and (01-01-2055 to 31-12-2099).

I have used the aggregate function to create an average per month like this. But now I have the average per month over the entire data set (2006-2100) and I want to have two lists (one for 01-01-2015 to 31-12-2054 and one for 01-01-2055 to 31-12-2099). I think I need to make a subset or split the data, but I cannot find how to combine this with the aggregate function. Thank you so much!

```
months = Alentejo_RCP4.5_Average$Month
Alentejo_RCP4.5_Average.myma = aggregate(x = Alentejo_RCP4.5_Average, 
                            by = list(months), FUN = mean)
```

I also tried this but it just takes the dates and not the attached values to the date.

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date("2015-01-01")+1:365, x=1:365)
list <- split(df,df$date<as.Date("2055-01-01"))

zz <- " Year Month Day Date Average_P
2006     1   1 2006-01-01   6.5
2007     1   2 2007-01-02   2.8
2055     3   3 2055-03-03   3.5
2058     3   4 2058-03-04   5.1
2060     5   5 2060-05-05   3.2"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting the datasets you can create a new column to distinguish between the two groups and take `mean` of each group and each month.

```
Data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), 
         group =  ifelse(Date < as.Date("2055-01-01"), 
                        'below_2055', 'above_2055'), 
         month = format(Date, '%m-%Y'))  %>%
  group_by(group, Date) %>%
  summarise(Average_P = mean(Average_P)) -> result
```

Or in base R :

```
Data$Date <- as.Date(Data$Date)
aggregate(Average_P~group + month, 
          transform(Data, 
                    group = ifelse(Date < as.Date("2055-01-01"), 
                            'below_2055', 'above_2055'),
                    month = format(Date, '%m-%Y')), mean) -> result
```

If you need final output as list you can then use `split`.

```
split(result,result$group)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried your script in the following way:

`aggregate(Alentejo_RCP4.5_Average$Average_P + Alentejo_RCP4.5_Average$Month, 
          transform(df, group = ifelse(date < as.Date('2055-01-01'), 
                                       'below_2055', 'above_2055'), 
                    month = format(date, '%m-%Y')), mean) -> result 
result`

But I get this error 

 `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame`

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you I will try again working with the df and x. Here is an example of the dataset.  
Year Month Day Date Average_QS Average_TN Average_TX Average_WS Average_P
2006  1   1 2006-01-01   4706.250   7.372229   14.47186  2.6203508 6.560209e+00

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to this, very thankful for your answers. I have tried to make a sample of the data set based on the page you send me. Hope it works!
`zz <- " Year Month Day       Date Average_QS Average_TN Average_TX Average_WS    Average_P
1   2006     1   1 2006-01-01   4706   7.37   14  2.6 6.5
2   2007     1   2 2007-01-02   5659   5.71   13  2.4 2.8
3   2055     3   3 2055-03-03   4427   5.72   13  1.9 3.5
4   2058     3   4 2058-03-04   3172   9.37   14  2.3 5.1
5   2060     1   5 2060-01-05   4947   8.32   13  2.6 3.2"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't go into the 'script mode' in the description, is it still usable like this?